# I believe my Q2 is saturated, which is leading to an uneven gain, What needs to change?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, bjt

[image: My Amp and its output, the gain is inconsistent]

The top half is right, but the lower half of my oscilloscope reading is not consistent with the top. I believe Q2 is saturated. Which component value is it recommended to modify? I know that the problem is related to the Q2 saturation, but I am not sure which component in the circuit is the cause of the inconsistent gain.